# Avoid VMware to ibernate the virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, standby

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.06 on VMware. I need this system keep running all the night. 
Is there any option in the settings to prevent the standby on the virtual machine?

Comment: Hibernation and Standby are functions of the computer, not the host. Have you tried simply configuring the computer not to hibernate in the way correct for Ubuntu.

Comment: In other words and to clarify a bit further what Mr. Music Man is saying, check the Guest OS hibernation and standby settings and configure those accordingly to not go to sleep. We assume the Host server hosting the VM guest OS does not go to sleep or hibernate or else you'd need to ensure that doesn't happen either... These settings are typically managed by the VM management interface with VMWare I don't think.